# FakeItEasy DbSet / IQueryable<T> - Entity Framework 6

Tags: unit-testing, dbcontext, entity-framework-6, fakeiteasy, dbset

I was wondering if anyone had a similar example to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069986/nsubstitute-dbset-iqueryablet) for FakeItEasy (original post is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx). I have been trying to find the correct setup, but could not get it right. I could not find any examples online. I am beginning to teach myself unit testing and I decided to use FakeItEasy. All my projects so far use the entity framework and do not use the Repository/UOW pattern since I consider DbSet and DbContext good enough for my small scale applications. I understand there are pros/cons with EF and unit testing, but I would still like to figure this out.  I am pretty sure I am way off with my attempt (see below) since the error I get is

> System.NotImplementedException: The member 'IQueryable.Provider' has
>   not been implemented on type 'DbSet`1Proxy' which inherits from
>   'DbSet`1'. Test doubles for 'DbSet`1' must provide implementations of
>   methods and properties that are used.

Any direction will be very helpful. Thank you.

```
var data = new List<Request> 
{ 
request1, 
request2, 
request3
}.AsQueryable();

var fakeDbSet = A.Fake<DbSet<Request>>();

A.CallTo(() => ((IQueryable<Request>)fakeDbSet).Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
A.CallTo(() => ((IQueryable<Request>)fakeDbSet).Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
A.CallTo(() => ((IQueryable<Request>)fakeDbSet).ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
A.CallTo(() => ((IQueryable<Request>)fakeDbSet).GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var fakeContext = A.Fake<RequestPortalContext>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Requests).Returns(fakeDbSet);

var service = new RequestReadService(fakeContext);
var requests = service.GetAllRequests();

Assert.AreEqual(3, requests.Count);
Assert.AreEqual("Test1", requests[0].Name);
Assert.AreEqual("Test2", requests[1].Name);
Assert.AreEqual("Test3", requests[2].Name);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with EntityFramework at all, and can't say what's going on for sure, since there's no stack trace with the NotImplementedException, but here's my guess:

You're seeing the exception raised from either the line that defines `service` or the one that calls `GetAllRequests`, not the `A.Fake<DbSet<Request>>()` line.

It sounds to me like the innards of `RequestReadService` (is that your class, I can't find it elsewhere?) or something it calls relies on the DbSet also implementing `IQueryable.Provider`. Now. I'm not sure why that wouldn't already be present. Perhaps it's the explicit implementation that throws it off. The best I can suggest (and I've not tried this, given my complete lack of EF6 knowledge), is to maybe try explicitly adding the interface to the fake:

```
A.Fake<DbSet<Request>>(builder => 
                         builder.Implements(typeof (IQueryable<Result>)));
```

Although after I typed that, I read [FakeItEasy issue 31](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/31), which I fear may apply, and so my idea may not work. Then again, if you're willing, give it a go. It may not take long.

Alternatively, in the short term, I'm not sure what other workarounds to suggest. Perhaps faking some of the interfaces that `DbSet` implements instead of faking `DbSet` itself?

**Updated**: after another question about this kind of thing, and actually grabbing EF6 so I could try it out, I created [Issue 477](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/477) to track what appears to be the underlying problem here.